# poblem with use the npm start in nodejs . 'nodemon' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: javascript, node.js

i create a project in `ubuntu` and i run and deploy that   , its worked fine .

now i change the operation system and a use the windows 10 and when i run this code `npm start` in vscode it show me this error :

```
> Store@1.0.0 start F:\Projects\Nodejs\Store
> nodemon server.js

'nodemon' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! Store@1.0.0 start: `nodemon server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the Store@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\programmer\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-27T11_34_26_614Z-debug.log
```

i install the nodemon :

```
    {
  "name": "Store",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

and download and install the nodejs in windows .

**whats the problem ? how can i solve this problem ??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve the problem . i delete all `node_module` and install that again with `npm install` command .